# Checking for Vertical Tabs in Apex?

Tags: apex

I have a few records in the database which have a text field.  Some of the values for this field include funny characters such as a Vertical Tab. I want to be able to read this values into memory and then check if they contain a vertical tab symbol in memory.

So something like....

```
List<Entity> entities = [SELECT MYFIELD, ID FROM ENTITY__C];

for (Entity entity: Entities) {
   if (entity.myfield.indexOf(verticaltab) > 0)
       ....
}
```

How do I explicitly check for the presence of the vertical tab?

Comment: Does '\v' work? If not, a regex search for '\\x0B' should work. (Gotta say in all my years I've never run into having to parse a vertical tab "in the wild"... where are you getting them from? MS Word?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code like this?

```
// How to get a string which contains the Vertical Tab character(ASCII code 11)
List<Integer> chars = new List<Integer> {11};
String verticalTab = String.fromCharArray(chars);

// A test String for comparison - the vertical tab is there, but it is not a display character
List<Integer> helloChars = new List<Integer>  {72, 101, 108, 108, 11, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100};
String helloWorld = String.fromCharArray(helloChars);
System.debug(helloWorld);

// The test returns true. Our example String does contain the vertical tab
System.debug(helloWorld.contains(verticalTab));
```